# Passing string from child tab activity to parent tab

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, bundle, parent-child

I have an  activity name "Tabs". It launches 4 different tabs , each with its own activities. It uses :

```
th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Tag1");
    Intent tabSelection = new Intent (this, ProfileSettings.class);

    tabSelection.putExtras(gotSettings);
    specs.setContent(tabSelection);
    specs.setIndicator("Settings",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_friendslist));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("Tag2");
    tabSelection = new Intent (this,InternationalRoamingService.class);
    specs.setContent(tabSelection);
    specs.setIndicator("IRS", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("Tag3");
    tabSelection = new Intent (this,Call.class);
    specs.setContent(tabSelection);
    specs.setIndicator("Call", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call));
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("Tag4");
    tabSelection = new Intent (this,WebSMS.class);
    specs.setContent(tabSelection);
    specs.setIndicator("SMS", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_start_conversation));
    th.addTab(specs);
```

I have no problems in passing the bundle "gotSettings" from the parent to the child. But how do I update the value of the bundle from the child activity OR pass a value from the child to the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two way for you :

- You can use [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) ,This is an example for it : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#usingintents_sub
- Another way is using a static parameter, you change it in your child activity and then use it in your parent activity. For example : Add this line in your child activity with 'ChildActivity' Class name `public static int myValue;` then set a parameter to it `myValue=25;` and use it in your parent activity : `myChildValue=ChildActivity.myValue;`

Comment: just accept the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. You must use static way(2) for get from spinners and use in another activity of your application